# What's the best way to combine multiple columns as single datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

This is a question I come back to from time to time. I have a dataset where multiple columns (*there are other columns*, these are just the ones pertinent to the question) are used to indicate a date and time. After casting them from float to int I now have:

```
year    mo      dy  hr min sec Valid Mag
1234    1886    9   1   2   51  4.0 7.3
1286    1893    6   4   2   27  4.0 7.0
1329    1897    8   5   0   10  4.0 7.7
1366    1901    8   9   9   23  4.0 7.2
1368    1901    8   9   18  33  4.0 7.4
```

**What is the clearest and most idiomatic way to convert this as a DateTime in a DataFrame that has more than just columns related to date and time?**

With a different project I used this:

```
sun['Date'] = sun['Year'].map(str)+ '-' + sun['Month'].map(str) + '-' + sun['Day'].map(str)
pd.to_datetime(sun['Date'], utc=False)
```

While this works, I think there certainly has to be a better, more generalized way. Specifically, I'm looking to combine the relevant fields into a DateTime but, again, *there are other fields in the data frame*. I've seen good responses for this in SQL, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Edit: I've received some solid answers for DataFrames of just date and times. However, the problem is that all result in the same error "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 19 elements, new values have 6 elements" so I've added in a couple of extra columns.

Answer (score 2):

Change column name then `pd.to_datetime`

```
df.columns = ['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']
out = pd.to_datetime(df)
Out[185]: 
1234   1886-09-01 02:51:00
1286   1893-06-04 02:27:00
1329   1897-08-05 00:10:00
1366   1901-08-09 09:23:30
1368   1901-08-09 18:33:45
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: That works great if it's just these six columns but since there are multiple other columns. You get a type mismatch.

Comment: @hrokr try with `rename` then df = df.rename({'Year' : 'year'....}), df['New'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']])

Answer (score 1):

So here is one way to do it, I don't know if its idiomatic.

The solution I found is using these column names

```
df.columns = [ 'year', 'month' , 'day' , 'hour' , 'minute'  ,'seconds']
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1886,9,1,2,51,0],
[1893,6,4,2,27,0],
[1897,8,5,0,10,0],
[1901,8,9,9,23,30],
[1901,8,9,18,33,45]])

#df.columns = [ 'Year', 'Mo' , 'Dy' , 'Hr' , 'Mn'  ,'Sec']

#use these column names instead of what you have
df.columns = [ 'year', 'month' , 'day' , 'hour' , 'minute'  ,'seconds']

#then you convert to date time
pd.to_datetime(df)
```

```
#output
0   1886-09-01 02:51:00
1   1893-06-04 02:27:00
2   1897-08-05 00:10:00
3   1901-08-09 09:23:30
4   1901-08-09 18:33:45
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys can be common abbreviations like [‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’, ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘us’, ‘ns’]) or plurals of the same [Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html*)

Comment: This works, but only for a list of date times. I'm looking for an elegant solution for a full-on DataFrame, with data.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this would be to use `datetime.strptime()` to create a `datetime` object and `df.apply()` it to a new column.

```
df['time'] = df.apply(lambda r: datetime.strptime(f"{r['Year']} {r['Mo']} {r['Dy']} {r['Hr']}:{r['Mn']}:{r['Sec']}", '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
df['time']
1234   1886-09-01 02:51:00
1286   1893-06-04 02:27:00
1329   1897-08-05 00:10:00
1366   1901-08-09 09:23:30
1368   1901-08-09 18:33:45
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: That works for dataframe with data, and I've upvoted it. I'm going to hold off on accepting to see if a more elegant solution comes forth. But I think it's important for those who come later with the same sort of problem to see this as viable.

Answer (score 0):

coerce df to string

use `str.pad` to fill values to minimum 2

Use `str.cat` to combine the values

Coerce the outcome to a datetime object.

Code below

```
pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.pad(width=2, side='left', fillchar='0')).str.cat(sep=''),axis=1))

1234   1886-09-01 02:51:00
1286   1893-06-04 02:27:00
1329   1897-08-05 00:10:00
1366   1901-08-09 09:23:30
1368   1901-08-09 18:33:45
```